# rake assets:precompile failed in rails 3.2.8 on Windows 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

When `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in our rails 3.2.8 app, it failed with the errors:

```
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!

  (in c:/D/code/rails_proj/biz-tools/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
```

...........

```
c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby193/bin/rak...]
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
```

There are only two datapicker in application.js and they are working fine when firing up the app. What could cause this failure? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you may need to install `sprockets` (and/or `rake`).

Comment: Installed sprockets and rake. The error is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend trying the `rubyracer` gem instead of `execjs` from past experience.

Alternatively, try commenting out `jquery-rails` or `jquery-ui-rails` gems from your Gemfile to see if these are causing you problems. You can always put `jquery` and `jquery-ui` directly into your assets.

Comment: @user938363 - didn't notice that you were running in Windows. I only spotted your folder names now. You could try installing [node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) on Windows to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I asked a friend to try your solution on execjs and it failed on his pc. But the code causing problem on my pc works well on his. I realized that it was windows issue. His is win 7 and mine is win 8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that execjs does not work on windows 8. Here is a [post](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81) about how to fix execjs runtimes for windows 8. But this fix seems not working for assets:precompile. We may have to wait for update of execjs for windows 8.

Comment: Linked thread solved some issues I encountered with execjs in W8.